# Custom grunt.helper values possible?

Tags: gruntjs

I am working on my own boilerplate using grunt's CLI possibilities like so `grunt init:webdesign-project` - for this I created a folder named `webdesign-project` within `node_modules/grunt/init` and a corresponding `webdesign-project.js` file. So far everything works great.

Now I wanted to insert my own "questions" with the `grunt.helper` function like this

```
grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'img_path', 'img')
```

however this gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.grunt.registerHelper.grunt.utils.spawn.cmd (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/tasks/init.js:573:17)
at Task.helper (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:117:19)
at Object.exports.template (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/tasks/init/webdesign-project.js:30:11)
at Object.module.exports.grunt.registerHelper.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/tasks/init.js:240:27)
at Object.task.registerTask.thisTask.fn (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:58:16)
at Task.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:341:36)
at Task.start (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:357:5)
at Object.grunt.tasks (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:143:8)
at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:36:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt:19:14)
```

Isn't it possible to define your own variables using this function?

EDIT: Does anybody know if a documentation for this function exists? (Couldn't find one yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve the "custom prompt" - in case anybody is interested:

Grunt's `grunt.helper('prompt_for', '...')` function apparently only takes a predefined set of values in lieu of '...'. Actually this should not be surprising, as there are some pretty unique features for some of those values (e.g. when you've entered `testproject` as your project's name, "(git://github.com/peter/testproject.git)" will automatically be proposed.

***Solution***: Take a look at the `.js` file of the gruntfile template (`node_modules/grunt/tasks/init/gruntfile.js`) - creating a custom prompt goes like this:

```
{
  name: 'img_path',
  message: 'Name the folder where all image files are located',
  default: 'img',
  // warning: '' couldn't find any use for this optional property
}
```

instead of

```
grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'img_path', 'img')
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify or add files within the `node_modules/` folder as they will be overwritten upon updating with npm. Take a look at the init docs for creating custom init templates: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_init.md#creating-custom-templates

I recommend copying one of the existing init templates to: `~/.grunt/tasks/init/webdesign-project.js` and modify from there.

Comment: But I don't have a `~/.grunt/` folder - should I create one? (Already tried reinstalling grunt several times - (I'm on linux, Ubuntu 12.04 to be precise)) - that's exactly what I did ;) I copied the jQuery template and adjusted it according to my needs

Comment: Yep, just create a `.grunt` folder in your home folder for init templates. FWIW, this is all changing in Grunt v0.4 :)

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much :) However I cannot use it anyway because grunt won't execute my `rename.json` (at least not the `"img/": "{%= img_path %}/"` part I did this for ^^)